# In javascript, match is not working the way it is supposed to

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a form where I have to ask the user for an email which has to end in .ca and the .match gives me an error (input1.match is not a function at newForm). Basically what I am trying to do is to make the input box border red if the address does not end in .ca and my regex should be correct. This is my code for the email input box:

```
var input1 = document.createElement('input');
input1.setAttribute("Id", "input1");
nform.appendChild(input1);
document.getElementById('input1').value;
var validate = input1.match(/\S+@\S+\.ca/);
if (!validate){
    input.style.borderColor = "Red";
}
```

Comment: String regex methods such as match would be executed against a string. What is the type of input1? Is it a string?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `input1` isn't a string, it's an input element you created. Call the match function on the value of `input1` like so:

```js
// ...
var inputValue = document.getElementById('input1').value;
var validate = inputValue.match(/\S+@\S+\.ca/);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably test this using Regular Expression, please find below code snippet:

```
// 
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
var regex = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.ca$');
var validate = regex.test(input1.value);
if (!validate){
  input1.style.borderColor = "Red";
}
//
```